# Unable to click on "install software prerequisite" for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, installation

I'm tring to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 SP2 on Windows Server 2008 SP2.

When I try to click on "Install software prerequisites", nothing happens and no installation wizard is opened.

Comment: what is the OS version....32bit or 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue when you trying to install the SharePoint 2010 foundation on windows server 32 bit environment.

SharePoint 2010 works only with 64 bit environment.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751(office.14).aspx